# Wordpress Problem : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I receive an error that you can see in the bottom of my question when trying to open my Wordpress site.

In the FTP directory I have tried to disable all plugins, then also all themes but it does not help.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   determine_locale() in
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/wordpress-4.9.2-ja-jetpack_webfont-undernavicontrol/wp-includes/class-wp-locale-switcher.php:48
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/wordpress-4.9.2-ja-jetpack_webfont-undernavicontrol/wp-settings.php(418):
>   WP_Locale_Switcher->__construct() #1
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/wordpress-4.9.2-ja-jetpack_webfont-undernavicontrol/wp-config.php(76):
>   require_once('/export/sd217/w...') #2
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/wordpress-4.9.2-ja-jetpack_webfont-undernavicontrol/wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('/export/sd217/w...') #3
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/wordpress-4.9.2-ja-jetpack_webfont-undernavicontrol/wp-blog-header.php(13):
>   require_once('/export/sd217/w...') #4
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/index.php(17):
>   require in
>   /export/sd217/www/jp/r/e/gmoserver/5/4/sd1019254/uniq-table.com/wordpress-4.9.2-ja-jetpack_webfont-undernavicontrol/wp-includes/class-wp-locale-switcher.php
>   on line 48

Comment: upgrade Wordpress version to 5.0 or later. `determine_locale()` function was introduce in WP version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Check below line is available in `wp-settings.php`

```
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/l10n.php' );
```

and make sure your PHP version is 7.2 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Wordpress 5.4.2 and downloaded the same version again and simply replaced the old `wp-includes` folder with the new one from freshly downloaded copy. Everything worked fine after that.